# In Android, how to send image from one activity to another selected from gallery?

Tags: android

[This is my code. Please give full code.And Received image should be appear after restart the app. Thank You][1]

```
     @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            String[] filePathColon={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursr=getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColon, null, null, null);
            cursr.moveToFirst();
            int columnindex=cursr.getColumnIndex(filePathColon[0]);
            final String picturepath=cursr.getString(columnindex);
            cursr.close();
            b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent  intent= new Intent(edit_student.this,student.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imagePath",picturepath );
                    startActivity(intent);}});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: pass bitmap to intent

Comment: Pass the image path to the next Activity

Answer (score 0):

send the image Uri to the second activity like this:

```
@override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),student.class);
intent.putParceleableExtra("imageUri",uri);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

In ur SecondActivity onCreate() get intent and get the uri,create a bitmap object from the uri and set it into the image view.

```
Uri retreivedUri = getIntent().getParceleableExra("imageUri");
```

Comment: I tried this code but it can't resolve the getParceleableExtra(() in both activity. so what should i do now. If possible please give me full code. thank you.